# Javascript: Catch and prevent duplicate row entry in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have two tables on my page, I can now add records from table 1 to table 2 but I want to add condition that will check if that new record is already exist on my table2. Here is my tables:

```
 <div id="opTableDiv" class="tableFixHead" ; style="margin-top: 5px;">
        <table class="sortable" border="1" id="table1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID Number</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>               
                <tr style="font-size:11px">
                </tr>                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>



 <div id="NewTraining" style="display:none">        
        <div id="opTableDiv" class="tableFixHead">            
            <table class="sortable" border="1" id="table2">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID Number</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Action</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="TrainTR" style="font-size:11px">
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's my javascript to add the new record and need validation here to avoid duplicate using id as its unique value:

```
function AddRecord(that, id, name) {

        var table = document.getElementById("table2");

        var row = table.insertRow(1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

        cell1.innerHTML = id;
        cell2.innerHTML = name;
```

Any suggestions/comments TIA.

Comment: Before calling `insertRow`, you'll need to loop through the existing rows to find out if the value already exists (either by some unique value, or the combination of all values)

Comment: Id recommend keeping track of the rows in some sort of data property. That way it is easy to determine.  Bonus points if you can index on the id (which i am presuming is the key you want to if it exists currently in the row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by:

1. first iterating the `tr` row elements of `table2` where, for each iteration
2. you check the `innerHTML` value of `td` cell elements on the current row to see if they match your input arguments and,
3. if a match is detected, early exit from the `AddRecord()` function via a `return` statement

There are many few ways this can be implemented. One option is to use the `querySelector()` method to extract the `tr` elements for iteration, and the specific `td` elements for comparison as follows:

```js
function AddRecord(that, id, name) {

  var table = document.getElementById("table2");

  /*
  Extract and iterate rows from tbody of table2
  */
  for(const tr of table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr")) {
     
    /*
    Extract first and second cell from this row
    */
    const td0 = tr.querySelector("td:nth-child(1)");
    const td1 = tr.querySelector("td:nth-child(2)");
    
    /*
    If this row has missing cells, skip it
    */
    if(!td0 || !td1) {
      continue;
    }
    
    /*
    Check if cells of existing tr row contain same contents
    as input arguments. Note also the use of == rather than 
    the use of === to allow type coercion when comparing 
    number id with string id.
    */
    if ((td0.innerHTML == id) && (td1.innerHTML == name)) {
      
      console.log(`Match found for ${id} and ${name}. Insert rejected`);
      return;
    }
  }  

  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

  cell1.innerHTML = id;
  cell2.innerHTML = name;
}

AddRecord('', 1, 'bob')
AddRecord('', 2, 'jon')
AddRecord('', 1, 'bob') // Should fail to insert
AddRecord('', 3, 'jon')
AddRecord('', 2, 'jon') // Should fail to insert
```

```html
<div id="NewTraining" >
  <div id="opTableDiv" class="tableFixHead">
    <table class="sortable" border="1" id="table2">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID Number</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Action</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="TrainTR" style="font-size:11px"> 
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great code Mhen. This saved me. Spent much time on this

Answer (score 0):

I have a function attached to a click event to add a row into a table, part of its implementation is this:

```
    var cartTotal = $('#cart_total').val();
    var cartDiscount = $('#cart_discount').val();
    var cartType = $('input[name="cart_type"]:checked').val();
    var cartTypeLabel = (
        cartType == 0 ? 'percentage' : 'fixed amount'
    );
    var duplicatedRow = false;

    $('#discount_rules_table tr').each(function (index, tr) {
        //if it is not the header row
        if(index!==0) {
            var tds = $(tr).find("td");
            if(duplicatedRow){
                return;
            } else {
                duplicatedRow = (
                    tds[0].innerHTML == cartTotal 
                    && tds[1].innerHTML == cartDiscount 
                    && tds[2].innerHTML.toLowerCase() == cartTypeLabel.toLowerCase()
                );
            }
        }
    });

    if(duplicatedRow) {
        return;
    }
    //...
```

With above code, I can avoid duplicated rows.